# Trouble writing to OutputStream socket

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket, outputstream

I am writing a simple web server program for class that sends files to the web browser on request. I have written as much as I could. The difficulty is getting the data written to the OutputStream. I don't know what I am missing. I couldn't get the simple request to show up on the web browser.

I wrote it to the "name" OutputStream but when I reload the tab in the browser with the URL: "http://localhost:50505/path/file.txt" or any other like that "localhost:50505" it doesn't show up what I wrote to the OutputStream "name". It is supposed to show that.

```
package lab11;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketImpl;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class main {
    private static final int LISTENING_PORT = 50505;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create listening socket.");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Listening on port " + LISTENING_PORT);
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("\nConnection from "
                        + connection.getRemoteSocketAddress());
                handleConnection(connection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server socket shut down unexpectedly!");
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            System.out.println("Exiting.");
        }
    }
    
    public static void handleConnection(Socket sok) {
        try {
//          Scanner in = new Scanner(sok.getInputStream());
            InputStream one = sok.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(one);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String rootDirectory = "/files";
            String pathToFile;
//          File file = new File(rootDirectory + pathToFile);
            StringBuilder request = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();
            while (!line.isEmpty()) {
                request.append(line + "\r\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
//          System.out.print(request);
            String[] splitline = request.toString().split("\n");
            String get = null;
            String file = null;
            for (String i : splitline) {
                if (i.contains("GET")) {
                    
                    get = i;
                    String[] splitget = get.split(" ");
                    file = splitget[1];
                }
            }
            }
            OutputStream name = sok.getOutputStream();
            Boolean doesexist = thefile.exists();
            if (doesexist.equals(true)) {
                
                PrintWriter response = new PrintWriter(System.out);
                response.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                response.write("Connection: close\r\n");
                response.write("Content-Length: " + thefile.length() + "\r\n");
                response.flush();
                response.close();
                
                sendFile(thefile, name);

            } else {
                System.out.print(thefile.exists() + "\n" + thefile.isDirectory() + "\n" + thefile.canRead());
            }

            
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while communicating with client: " + e);
        }
        finally {  // make SURE connection is closed before returning!
            try {
                sok.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Connection closed.");
        }
    }
    

    
    private static void sendFile(File file, OutputStream socketOut) throws
      IOException {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socketOut);
        while (true) {
          int x = in.read(); // read one byte from file
          if (x < 0)
             break; // end of file reached
          out.write(x);  // write the byte to the socket
       }
       out.flush();
    }
}
```

So, I don't know what I really did wrong.

When I load the browser with localhost:50505 it just says can't connect or localhost refused to connect.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: I think because you have to remove the package lab11 on the top.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the HTTP response in `System.out`. You should write it in `name`, after the headers, in the body of the response. You probably want to describe it with a [Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-content-type) header to make the receiver correctly show the file.